# How do I get input from linux command line into my Python script?

Tags: python, linux, command-line, argv, sys

I am trying to execute a command on a file such as chmod in a python script. How can I get the file name from command line to the script? I want to execute the script like so ./addExecute.py blah 
Where blah is the name of some file. The code I have is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import os
file = sys.argv[1]
os.system("chmod 700 file")
```

I keep getting the error that it cannot access 'file' no such file or directory.

Comment: Thanks guys I changed it to:    os.chmod (file, 0700)   works great now!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
os.system("chmod 700 file")
                     ^^^^--- literal string, looking for a file named "file"
```

You probably want

```
os.system("chmod 700 " + file)
                       ^^^^^^---concatenate your variable named "file"
```

Comment: Note that this isn't a safe way to perform the `chmod`. Also, Python has `os.chmod` built in.

Answer (score 1):

It could be something like

```
os.system("chmod 700 %s" % file)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
os.system("chmod 700 file")
```

file is not replaced by its value. Try this :

```
os.system("chmod 700 " + file)
```

BTW, you should check if the script was executed with parameters (you could have an error such as "list index out of range")

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other answers, you need to place the value of the variable *file* instead.
However, following the suggested standard, you should use format and state it like

```
os.system("chmod 700 {:s}".format(file))
```

Using

```
os.system("chmod 700 %s" % file)
```

is discouraged, cf. also [Python string formatting: % vs. .format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082452/python-string-formatting-vs-format).